# Excel VB/Macro InStr Exact Search

Tags: vba, excel

I needed something that would search a column in Excel and output something if the search matched. Most of it works but similar values do not seem to work. For example:

```
Sub ConvertComputerNames()

Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range

Set SrchRng = Range("A2:A200")

For Each cel In SrchRng
    If InStr(1, cel.Value, "W7ADH") Then
        cel.Offset(0, 7).Value = "LTW7ADH"
    End If
    If InStr(1, cel.Value, "ADH") Then
        cel.Offset(0, 7).Value = "LTW10ADH"
    End If

 Next cel

End Sub
```

In this case, both will show LTW10ADH. Is there a way to make it so it shows the correct value? I need it to be an exact match. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if *exact* match means the cell value must *exactly* match the given string then you won't use `Instr()` and just compare cell content:

```
Sub ConvertComputerNames()

    Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range

    Set SrchRng = Range("A2:A200")

    For Each cel In SrchRng
        If cel.Value = "W7ADH" Then
            cel.Offset(0, 7).Value2 = "LTW7ADH"
        End If
        If cel.Value = "ADH" Then
            cel.Offset(0, 7).Value2 = "LTW10ADH"
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

in this case the most proper construct would be either a `If ... ElseIf ... End If`:

```
For Each cel In SrchRng
    If cel.Value = "W7ADH" Then
        cel.Offset(0, 7).Value = "LTW7ADH"
    ElseIf cel.Value = "ADH" Then
        cel.Offset(0, 7).Value = "LTW10ADH"
    End If
Next
```

or a `Select Case ... End Select` one:

```
For Each cel In SrchRng
    Select Case cel.Value
        Case "W7ADH"
            cel.Offset(0, 7).Value = "LTW7ADH"
        Case "ADH"
            cel.Offset(0, 7).Value = "LTW10ADH"
    End Select
Next
```

---

while if you actually need a *partial* match, then @KenWhite pointed out the issue and another way of properly handling it is via `Select Case` construct again:

```
Sub ConvertComputerNames()
    Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range

    Set SrchRng = Range("A2:A200")

    For Each cel In SrchRng
        Select Case True
            Case InStr(1, cel.Value, "W7ADH")
                cel.Offset(0, 7).Value = "LTW7ADH"
            Case InStr(1, cel.Value, "ADH")
                cel.Offset(0, 7).Value = "LTW10ADH"
        End Select
    Next
End Sub
```

at the first matching `Case` condition, the corresponding code is executed and then the code exits the `Select Case - End Select` block, so it's a matter of placing the checks in proper order

Comment: Thank you very much! I went with the If/ElseIf and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

Of course they do. Your second test matches both the first and second options, so the second will always apply. Change it to If..Else If instead; if the first match succeeds, the second will never be executed.

```
Sub ConvertComputerNames()
Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range

    Set SrchRng = Range("A2:A200")

    For Each cel In SrchRng
      If InStr(1, cel.Value, "W7ADH") Then
          cel.Offset(0, 7).Value = "LTW7ADH"
      Else If InStr(1, cel.Value, "ADH") Then
          cel.Offset(0, 7).Value = "LTW10ADH"
      End If
    Next cel
End Sub
```